# binding not refreshing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and I need your help to update the content of the HTML after the user logged in.
In fact the HTML load the controller only once when I load the page, meaning when the user is not yet logged. but after the login the HTML did not refresh the page an display the user's login? how can I fix that.
Below is my HTML

```
<section class="hero hero-1 hero-small" ng-controller="HomeController">

    <header class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container" ng-controller="UserController">
            {{username}}
            <nav>
                <a class="navbar--logo" ui-sref="home">EspritAcademy</a>
            </nav>
            <nav>
                <ul class="navbar--list pull-right">
                    <li class="navbar--list-item"><a ui-sref="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar--list-item"><a ui-sref="#">Courses</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar--list-item" ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a
                        ui-sref="login">Sign in</a></li>

                    <li class="navbar--list-item dropdown"
                        ng-controller="DropdownCtrl" dropdown is-open="status.isopen"
                        ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><a ui-sref="#"
                        class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" dropdown-toggle
                        ng-disabled="disabled"> <b>{{username}}</b><b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left: inherit; right: 0;">
                            <li><a ui-sref="#">My Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="#">Account Settings</a></li>
                            <li ng-click="logout()"><a ui-sref="home">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <!-- <li class="navbar--list-item" ng-click="logout()"
                        ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><a ui-sref="home">Déconnexion</a></li> -->

                    <li class="navbar--list-item" ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a
                        class="rounded-button blue-button" ui-sref="register">Start
                            learning</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</section>
```

and my controller:

```
controller(
            "HomeController",
            function HomeController($scope, sessionService) {
                $scope.isLoggedIn = sessionService.isLoggedIn;
                $scope.logout = sessionService.logout;
            }).controller(
                    "UserController",
                    function UserController($scope, accountService) {
                        console.log("Hello");
                        var loggedUser = {};
                        loggedUser = accountService.getuser();
                        if ((loggedUser)) {
                            $scope.username = loggedUser.username;
                            console.log("username : ", $scope.username);
                        }
                    }).controller('DropdownCtrl',
            function($scope, $log) {
                $scope.status = {
                    isopen : false
                };

                $scope.toggled = function(open) {
                };
            });
```

the problem that I'm facing is with the display of {{username}}.
below is the factory used to get user details using rest technology with Java back-end.

```
factory(
            'accountService',
            function($resource, sessionService) {
                var service = {};
                service.register = function(account, profile, success,
                        failure) {
                    if (profile.id == 1) {
                        var Account = $resource("/rest/account");
                        Account.save({}, account, success, failure);
                    } else {
                        var Account = $resource("/rest/account/teacher");
                        Account.save({}, account, success, failure);
                    }
                };
                service.userExists = function(account, success, failure) {
                    var Account = $resource("/rest/account");
                    var data = Account.get({
                        username : account.username,
                        password : account.password
                    }, function() {
                        console.log("user details : ", data);
                        var accounts = data.username;
                        if (accounts && accounts.length !== 0) {
                            console
                                    .log("profile id :",
                                            data.userProfile.id);
                            service.data = data;
                            success(account);
                        } else {
                            failure();
                        }
                    }, failure);
                };
                service.getuser = function() {
                    return service.data;
                };
                return service;
            })
```

I don't need to keep refreshing my page I just need to only load the UserController after the user login. Is it possible with ng-if or Other way?

Comment: Please show `accountService.getuser()`   code. Your `if(loggedUser)` is causing the problem but would help to see what `getuser()` returns

Comment: @charlietfl I don't think that the problem may be related to accoutService.getuser cause I have no problem displaying the username with the same controller but in other screens that loads just after login.

Comment: but it certainly is when you only set `$scope.username` if it is not returning an object with the `username property. Then when you update the object in `getuser()` there is nothing to bind to in controller

Comment: @charlietfl That's the problem, in fact What I need to do is to told the HTML to load the usercontroller only when the user is logged in otherwise $scope.username will be always empty

Comment: can use `ng-if` to leave the html out, or a directive or `ng-include`. Numerous ways to do it

Comment: @charlietfl would you please give me an example using ng-if or ng-include ?

Comment: for ng-if is same as your ng-show. `ng-include` allows setting dynamic url based on scope variables

Comment: @charlietfl it's not working with ng-if  I just added this `<b ng-if="isLoggedIn()">{{username}}</b>` and ng-include will not display what  I need, in fact I just need to display the user's username after his login

Comment: did you try my answer? Your code won't set the scope variable is why you aren't succeeding

Comment: @charlietfl is not that the problem cause if I just set $scope.loggedUser = "Hello" he will be displayed correctly with no problem but he will not update it after login he will keep it always like that, like it need an action to update the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to instantiate the user controller only when the user is logged in, which is currently not the case.

Try changing this

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="UserController">
```

to this

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="UserController" ng-if="isLoggedIn()">
```

Comment: yep :) ca marche :) Thank you Haykel, I was using the if condition in controller and I thought that I will not have a problem when the username is empty, but using ng-if that will only fill that var only when the condition is validated. I also updated the HTML code to get a correct display :) Thank you again @Haykel Ben Jemia

Answer (score 0):

Since `getuser()` always returns an object try the following

```
 function HomeController($scope, accountService) {
     //will always be object but may not have `username` property
     $scope.loggedUser = accountService.getuser();
 }
```

Then in markup use

```
{{loggedUser.username}}
```

So now when the `username` property gets updated in your service it will be bound all the way through to the view

Comment: it's the same issue, the problem that I'm facing is that when I load the page and the user is not yet logged in so the loggedUser var will be empty meaning that {{loggedUser.username}} will be also empty and will not be updated after the user logged in.

Comment: oops   change this `var service = {data: ''};`. I misread the return

Comment: same thing :( it doesn't update the display after login.

Comment: it should if you followed my approach and getuser is returning an object, create a plunker demo and use `$timeout` as delay to mimic the login

Comment: let me give you more details. you see the block with if condition in the userontroller it's never validated even if the loggeduser is not empty I just got the hello in my console but it never display the username : user1 for example, the second console.log in the controller, and that's the problem that I'm trying to solve why the query after the if condition is never executed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with plunker, but you can find the source here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b8eiydxmyveksec/AABwJTiy4j56wZUKHnHzOC9ha/src/main/webapp?dl=0